# Join CSV and shapefile files using common field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

[image]I am trying to join a .CSV and a shapefile using "join attributes by field value." The common field I'm using is "County_Cit." I get an error message when I try this.

Do you know what I need to change to be able to join these files?

[image]

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Can you check the message log panel and post its content?

Comment: Please dont post a question three times. Instead edit your question to add additional informations.

Comment: It's a different join.  Not the same question.

Comment: I posted the message log above. Do you know how to get this thread reopened?  It's not a duplicate, just a different issue with a different join I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

279 input features could not be matched. Could be for a few reasons, the obvious ones being

1. The input features don't match! Remember 'Yellow_Medicine_Wood Lake township' does not equal 'Yellow_medecine Wood_lake township '

In the above example, cases are wrong, medicine is spelt wrong, an underscore is different AND there is a space at the end. all common mismatch criteria for string data comparisons.

2. In your join settings, you have selected 'Take Attributes of First matching feature only (one-to-one) - Its possible that one of your tables has a duplicate, which means any further matches won't occur.

BUT im assuming your more concerned about the fact that a temporary output file is not created. Sometimes in QGIS, if you do not specify a physical output file, the geoprocessing tool doesn't work - other times, it depends on the output format.

HOWEVER - Im just comparing your input GUI, to the output log. In the screen capture of the GUI, your Input 1 file is the shapefile. However on the output log screen capture , it is saying that Input_2 i the shapefile. (INPUT_2 : C"\Users\blah_blah\file.shp)

So just double check that your input 1 is actually the shapefile. It needs the geographic file to be input 1 for it to create a geographic output file (a shapefile).

If your shapefile is set to input 1 on the gui, BUT your log specifies the shapefile as INPUT_2, then maybe its a bug in your version? Try swapping your inputs on the GUI. (ie: Make the CSV file input 1).

Comment: Ok thanks.  I swapped input 1 and input 2 but still got an error message.  I attached the message log above.

Comment: thats not quite the message log - If you Right Click on the Toolbars, and enable the Log Messages Panel, this will give you the logs people are asking for .... and yer copy-paste :)